# Filament translation navigationLabel

Tags: laravel-filament

I'm looking for in doc how to translate `navigationLabel` of a resource
I've tried

```php
public static function setNavigationLabel(?string $navigationLabel): void
{
   self::$navigationLabel = __('filament::pages/town-halls.TownHall');
}
```

and create a file in lang/vendor/filament/es/pages/town-halls.php with

```php
<?php

return [
    'TownHall' => 'Ayuntamientos',
];
```

But not works

Also tries

```php
public static function setNavigationLabel(?string $navigationLabel): string
{
   return __('filament::pages/town-halls.TownHall');
}
```

Also tries

```php
public static function getLabel(): string
{
   return __('filament::resources/pages/town-halls.TownHall');
}
```

In this case PHPStorm with Laravel Idea plugin show me correct path for translation, but in browser show code instalead traslation.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the getNavigationLabel method like the following:

```
 protected static function getNavigationLabel(): string
 {
      return __('filament::resources/pages/town-halls.TownHall');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getNavigationLabel(): string
{
    return __('filament::resources/pages/town-halls.TownHall');
}
```

reference => https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/upgrade-guide#method-signature-changes